# Insert the QR code generated into pdf document in react-pdf/renderer

Tags: reactjs, pdf, react-pdf

I'm currently using both QRcode.react to generate the codes and `@react-pdf/renderer` to create the pdf document.

```
var QRCode = require('qrcode.react');
< QRCode value="http://facebook.github.io/react/" />
```

**Problem**: The QR code only works when outside the pdf document. I want the QR code can be shown on the pdf document.

So, any solution to this?